# compiling samba-shared code fails in qt

Tags: qt, qt4, samba

I spent the last 2 days trying to make qt on windows 7 compile a samba-shared project hosted on a linux machine (which is visible on win7 as volume Z).

The problem is that after the first modification of any of the source file, the compilation simply does nothing. I mean literally, no errors, no warning. You click "rebuild", and you instantly get the green bar as if everything was recompiled (and it is a large project so it would take a while), but nothing is actually done. All I see in the compilation output is "Running Jom.exe on *path*" and (1 ms later) "Jom.exe returned normally"

At first I tought samba shared files were somehow changed in attributes or the like, so I checked and indeed they change to +x on the linux box, but even after resetting the original permissions the compiler silently refuses to compile. Actually it is not even invoked at all.

If I duplicate such "modified - not working" tree on the win7 machine, I have the same behaviuor, while if I duplicate the tree from the linux box straight from the beginning, qt works as expected.

I dont think its a qt issue, but I really have no clue on how to fix this, I cant even try NFS since win7 is Pro and has no additional NFS support.

Of course clearing the project an re-running qmake doesnt change anything.

Just for completeness, note that if I make some change to a source file from windows the file is indeed changed in the linux box, its just the compiler that seems not to be invoked anymore

Comment: you are doing it on qt creator, what happens when you try to compile in the command line which `qmake` then `make`??

Comment: yes Im doing it from QtCreator, I didnt try to qmake & make manually, I will try asap TY